# SymbolSet breaks on Safari based browsers

Tags: css, safari, sass, webfonts, compass-sass

Chome:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

My compass .scss code

```
@include icon-font('SSStandard', inline-font-files('ssstandard/ss-standard.woff', woff, 'ssstandard/ss-standard.ttf', truetype,'ssstandard/ss-standard.svg', svg),'ssstandard/ss-standard.eot');
// Custom code goes here..
@include icon-font('SSSocialRegular', inline-font-files('ssstandard-social/ss-social-regular.woff',woff, 'ssstandard-social/ss-social-regular.ttf', truetype,'ssstandard-social/ss-social-regular.svg', svg),'ssstandard/ss-social-regular.eot');
// Examples of using the icon mixin:
// @include icon('user');
@include font-face("Montserrat", inline-font-files("montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf",truetype, "montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.woff", woff));

@mixin ss-icon($name, $symbol,$font:"SSStandard") {
  .x-tab .x-button-icon.#{$name}:before,.x-button .x-button-icon.#{$name}:before{
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family:$font;
  }
  .#{$name}:before{
    font-family:$font;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  }
}

@include ss-icon('ss-write', '✎');
@include ss-icon('ss-writingdisabled', '');
@include ss-icon('ss-navigate-right', '▻');
@include ss-icon('ss-navigate-left', '◅');
@include ss-icon('ss-facebook','','SSSocialRegular');
@include ss-icon('ss-twitter','','SSSocialRegular');
@include ss-icon('ss-mail','✉','SSSocialRegular');
@include ss-icon('ss-info','ℹ');
@include ss-icon('ss-home','⌂');
@include ss-icon('ss-settings','⚙');
@include ss-icon('ss-sync','');
```

Both SS standard and ss social regular do not display properly, but Montserrat does.

The home symbol displays as "Γîé" on safari and if I replace that content on the inspector with the correct symbol, it displays correctly.

The charset is "UTF-8" on both my scss file and the html file

Comment: please post the generated css

Comment: It's a giant file with several data urls, but I will

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aFJ28vBT

Comment: The recommendation for using special characters in the content property is to use the unicode values:  `content: "\f000"`

Comment: thanks cimmanon. I learned that the hard way. switching it to a MAC and compass functioned correctly. Guess i'll go buy a mac for fewer headaches with ruby related programs.